# How to activate wordpress RTL styesheet while having backend in LTR?

Tags: wordpress, right-to-left

I have sahifa WordPress theme which have RTL style sheet with it, i want to activate RTL style sheet on my website but it is only possible when i change WordPress language from English to Arabic or Persian,..etc, but i don't want to do so, so tell me a method that through which i can activate RTL style sheet while having backed in English.

Please make you answer easier and simple as i am not developer, i am just going to make an URDU site for which i need to activate Right to Left Style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [this](https://wpml.org/documentation/theme-compatibility/build-rtl-wordpress-themes/). Although there's one in WordPress site ([here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support)) which actually says the same thing.